# Display MySQL Rows With PHP - Table Dependency

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I got 2 MYSQL tables: users & posts.

I'd like to echo all users who haven't got an entry in the "posts" table - without adding a SQL-query inside a mysql_fetch_array-while-function.

I heard that this can be done with JOIN or UNION, but I couldn't manage to write the right SQL-query. I'm also not really sure whether to use JOIN or UNION - or maybe none of them, because there is another solution?

```
table: users            table: posts

id |  name            post_id | user_id 
1  |   tom               7    |    1  
2  |   bob               8    |    2    
3  |   jon               9    |    1
```

I don't want to do this ...

```
include_once( 'connect.php' );

$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );

while ( $row = $result->fetch_array() ) {
   $id = $row['id'];
   $name = $row['name'];

   $check = "SELECT user_id FROM posts WHERE user_id != '$id'";
   $result_check = mysqli_query( $con, $check );
      /*** i want to prevent running a sql query inside a while-function ***/
   $count = mysqli_num_rows( $result_check );

   if( $count == 0  ) {
      echo $name . '<br />';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `JOIN`; a staple of SQL.

In this case, you're looking to `INNER JOIN` where `users.id` equals `posts.user_id`:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name
        FROM users INNER JOIN posts
        ON users.id = posts.user_id
        WHERE posts.user_id != '$id'";
```

This will return the information in the `users` table for the user who *doesn't* have an `id` matching in the `posts` table.

If you also want to find their corresponding posts, simply specify this in the `SELECT`. Keeping track of which table you're referencing is made easier by the use of aliases. Note the `u` and `p` in the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT u.id, u.name, p.posts
        FROM users u INNER JOIN posts p
        ON u.id = p.user_id
        WHERE p.user_id != '$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
check = "SELECT user_id, name FROM users WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT 
         user_id FROM posts GROUP BY user_id)";
```

This should return what you want. The sub-query will find all user_ids in posts table. Then the main query will return all the user_ids that are not in that result.

There may be more efficient ways with a JOIN or UNION but this should work. However, I do suggest striving for efficiency with your SQL queries. That has a large impact on the performance of your application.